# Chrome STT using given wav file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, wav

I want to do STT in Chrome browser with a given wav file.

I tried the following code, but it only uses audio from the microphone of my PC..
I wished it utilizes the wav file I provided.

```
  <script>
    const audioUrl = 'http://localhost/wav/snd_thank_en.wav';
    const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;

    const startRecognitionBtn = document.getElementById('start-recognition-btn');
    const recognitionResult = document.getElementById('recognition-result');

    startRecognitionBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      startRecognitionBtn.disabled = true;
      recognition.start();
      console.log('Speech recognition started');
    });

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      let finalTranscript = '';
      let interimTranscript = '';
      for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
        const transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
        if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
          finalTranscript += transcript;
        } else {
          interimTranscript += transcript;
        }
      }
      console.log('Final Transcript:', finalTranscript);
      console.log('Interim Transcript:', interimTranscript);
      recognitionResult.textContent = finalTranscript;
    };

    // Fetch the audio file and start the speech recognition
    fetch(audioUrl)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(audioData => {
        const context = new AudioContext();
        const source = context.createBufferSource();

        context.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.connect(context.destination);
          source.start(0);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching audio file:', error);
      });
  </script>
```

I need help to use given wav file or wav data array for STT.